# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la página web de mi servidor Nginx desde un cliente?

Tags: linux, servidor, nginx, despliegue

estoy intentando acceder a la página web de mi servidor Nginx desde un cliente.
Mi servidor tiene la siguiente configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entre ellos hay conexión, he realizado un ping a la ip del servidor desde la ip del cliente y llegan los paquetes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando consulto la web del servidor desde el cliente me dice que no tiene conexión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo los siguientes puertos abiertos en el servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La IP parece la 89, no la 88

Comment: Cierto, aún así me sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: ¿te responde al ping?  ¿que puertos muestra abiertos si haces un `netstat -anp | grep -i tcp` en el servidor ?  ¿alguno de ellos es el 80?  ¿ en cual ves el nginx corriendo, si lo ves?

Comment: Sí, me responde al ping

Comment: Esta en el puerto 80

Comment: ¿Si desde el propio servidor haces un `wget https://10.227.6.89` llega a descargar algo?  (ponte en una carpeta vacia para eso, pues descargaras su pagina)

Comment: Me dice connection refused

Comment: Prueba sin la s de http... es decir, `wget http://10.227.6.89`

Comment: Vale, ahora si se ha descargado

Comment: Pues prueba esa url en la otra maquina en lugar de la https

Comment: Listo, era por la 's' , ya me abre la página en el cliente. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: No problem :-)  Saludos!